# Retrieve URL Value but keeps returning (NULL)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying retrieve the string value of a URL (objResultQuiz.strResultUrl), but the console keeps returning (null)

```
imgView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:objResultQuiz.strResultUrl];    
imgView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:objResultQuiz.strResultUrl];
strIMGResult = [imgView.imageURL absoluteString];
WebServiceHelper *webHelper = [[WebServiceHelper alloc] init];
webHelper.strIMG = strIMGResult;
NSLog(@"Value of IMG is %@", webHelper.strIMG);
```

Console:
2014-08-22 19:47:09.506 Voo[521:109716] Value of IMG is (null)

Comment: NSLog strIMGResult, my guess is imgView.imageURL is null as well.

Comment: yes, is there any way to obtain the string?

Comment: add NSLog(@"%@", objResultQuiz.strResultUrl);

Comment: The problem is clearly that objResultQuiz.strResultUrl is never set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the original objResultQuiz.strResultUrl is nil, so when you set strIMGResult to the absoluteString of nil, it's still nil. Later when you set this nil value to the webHelper.strIMG and log the value, its of course nil.

Once you figure out why the strResultUrl is nil, your problem should be solved.

Comment: managed to solve the issue. thanks for steering me in the right direction.